# Uninitialized local variable error on a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to finish an assignment for my C++ class, and I've hit a problem that I haven't been able to find an answer to thus far.

What I'm trying to do is to create a vector that can grow indefinitely until the user breaks the loop. This vector must hold class objects to hold student names and grade information. I have the class working; the only part of the program that seems to be giving me trouble at this point is the vector.

I keep getting this error code:

> error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'students' used

Here is my function:

```
void vectorfctn(){
   vector<student> *students; //I'm assuming this is what is causing the error
   string stud;
   double ex1;
   double ex2;
   double hw;
   double fex;
   char exit;

   do {
    cout << "Enter Student Name" << endl; cin >> stud;
    cout << endl << "Enter First Exam" << endl; cin >> ex1;
    cout << endl << "Enter Second Exam" << endl; cin >> ex2;
    cout << endl << "Enter Homework" << endl; cin >> hw;
    cout << endl << "Enter Final" << endl; cin >> fex;

    student* s1 = new student(stud, ex1, ex2, hw, fex);
    s1->calcFinalGrade();
    students->push_back(*s1); //This is the line referenced by visual studio in the error

    cout << "Would you like to continue? y or n" << endl;
    cin >> exit;
    delete s1;
   } while (exit != 'n');

for (size_t i = 0; i < students->size(); i++) {
    cout << students->at(i).calcFinalGrade() << endl;
}
};
```

How would I initialize my vector without limiting its size? I suck with vectors, and don't really understand them a whole lot, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Vectors grow on their own. There is no need to dynamically allocate one -
 that has to be an antipattern. Also why create a `new` student when you are just going to delete it anyways?

Answer (score 3):

`students` vector doesn't need to be pointer.

Replace
`vector<student> *students;` with `vector<student> students;`

and

`students->pushback()` to `students.pushback()`

Answer (score 1):

First, declare the `vector` *object*, instead of pointer.

```
vector<student> students;
```

Second, declare the `student` *locally*, instead of pointer and `new`.

```
student s1(stud, ex1, ex2, hw, fex);
```

Third, `push_back`.

```
students.push_back(s1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `vector *students;` creates a pointer of `vector` and not the vector itself. When you are trying to call its member function via ->, there is no vector created yet, thus you are not able to push_back anything inside and thus the error.

To fix this, just remove * at the `vector *students;` and replace all `students->push_back` with `students.push_back`

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. I didn't consider that, and that did the trick. Thank you much

Answer (score 0):

You were creating a pointer to the vector (declaration) but not actually creating the vector (definition).  As others have said, simply create the vector on the stack.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void vectorfctn() {
    vector<Student> students;

    string stud;
    double ex1;
    double ex2;
    double hw;
    double fex;
    char exit;

    do {  // todo: validate user input
        cout << "Enter Student Name" << endl;        getline(cin, stud);
        cout << endl << "Enter First Exam" << endl;  cin >> ex1;
        cout << endl << "Enter Second Exam" << endl; cin >> ex2;
        cout << endl << "Enter Homework" << endl;    cin >> hw;
        cout << endl << "Enter Final" << endl;       cin >> fex;

        //Student s1 = Student(stud, ex1, ex2, hw, fex);
        //s1.calcFinalGrade();  // does this really need to be here?  It's also used below in the for loop
        //students.push_back(s1);
        students.push_back(Student(stud, ex1, ex2, hw, fex));

        cout << "Would you like to continue? y or n" << endl; cin >> exit;

    } while (exit != 'n');

    for (auto student : students) { cout << student.calcFinalGrade() << endl; }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Use push_back to append whatever you want to the vector.

```
vector<int> myVec;
myVec.push_back(2);
myVec.push_back(3);
```

I think your syntax for push_back is incorrect.
Did this help?